# How to let multiple keepalived instances run in same server?

Tags: linux, namespaces, network-programming, keep-alive

In linux, I created 2 network namespaces, ns1 and ns2, then run keepalived in each of namespace, like this:

```
 ip netns exec qlbaas-2180946e-fc7f-42d8-baa8-ae9164bf15da keepalived  -f /keep_lb22.conf  -p /var/run/keepalivednew.pid -r  /var/run/keepalivednewch.pid
```

In ns1, keepalived runs well, but for the second keepalived that runs in ns2 will fail with log "daemon is already running".

Is there any way to fix the problem? I have to run keepalived in 2 namespace.

Or I have to use PID namespace?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, made a mistake, the pid file already exists, if pid file doesn't exist, the problem will gone.